# How can I change a path in Powershell?

Tags: python, powershell, notepad++

[image: Powershell Struggle -_-]

Hello All! I recently bought a textbook about Python. I am currently using Notepad++ as an editor. I am trying to open my ex1.py file(located on Desktop) using Powershell. For example, I am trying to use "python ex1.py" command to open my text file on Powershell. Everytime when I try using "cd C:\Desktop" to change my working directory, I get these errors as above.

Comment: If you have a directory named C:\Desktop, try typing in `cd \Desktop`.

Comment: right click on file and click on properties. there you will see a path against Location. copy that path then in cmd type cd  and then paste the path you copied. poof saw the magic...

Comment: Oh it worked ! Thank you so much. Is there a way to set Powershell's default working directory to Desktop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

The command you are looking for is

```
set-location $env:userprofile\desktop
```

or short

```
sl $env:userprofile\desktop    # sl is an alias for set-location
```

or even

```
cd $env:userprofile\desktop    # cd is another alias for set-location
```

### Explanation

A user's desktop path, like many other systems paths, depends on the exact version of the Windows OS you are using. These paths have been renamed and moved a lot between different OS releases, therefore it is the safest bet to ustilize the environment variables to locate the current user's home directory. The PowerShell `env:` drive enables access to these definitions:

Try typing this into the PoSh console:

```
get-childitem env:   # gives a list of all environment variables defined 
ls env:              # same, via alias
dir env:             # same, via alias

dir $env:userprofile   # shows contents of the current users (your) home directory
```

The `Desktop` folder is right within that home folder, thus:

```
set-location $env:userprofile\desktop
```

will set the current location to the desired folder, and it will do this in a portable manner.

Comment: It works! Thank you! but do I always have to do this to open a file on Desktop? can I just set its default directory to Desktop?

Comment: Put the command into your PoSh startup script. Enter `notepad $profile` and edit the file that shows up like any *.ps1 file. These commands are executed whenever you open PowerShell next time. See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/28/editing-your-profile-file.aspx

Comment: I am sorry but I have no clue how to get there...I just started using Power Shell

Comment: Simple. The `$profile` variable is predef9ined, it holds the name of the script PowerShell will look for when started. The file is a simple text file. It works very much like writing a batch file, except that the target is PowerShell. It is not that hard to understand, really. Just ave a look at the blog I mentioned, it is full of nice helpful tips like this one.

Answer (score -1):

Try to type this :

```
cd "C:/Documents and Settings/YOURUSERNAME/Desktop"
```

As a standard user, you may not have your Desktop folder located in C:/

Comment: Somehow I always keep my files on Desktop. It seems more easier..I will try your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: We use backslashes on Windows systems. Slashes may work in some cases, but they are not guaranteed to work always.